# angular 4 - Iterate json objects

Tags: angular

Below is the code to get the json data

```
    export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
          observableBooks: Observable<Book[]>
          books: Book[];
          errorMessage: String;
          constructor(private bookService: BookService,private loki: LokiService) { }
          ngOnInit(): void {
               this.observableBooks = this.bookService.getBooksWithObservable();
               this.observableBooks.subscribe(
                   books =>  this.books = books,
                   error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);

        this.observableBooks.forEach(element => {
          console.log(element);/// here I can get the json format as expected

// console.log(element.fname); //this is not working
//  console.log(element.lname);// this is not working
        });

      }
    }
```

Consider the json as like below

```
[{fname: "name1",lname: "name2"},{fname: "name3",lname: "name4"}]
```

I want to get the values of fname and lname.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Is this an array of objects?, Then it should be enclosed in `[]`.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(element[0].fname)` ?

Comment: yes, it is a array of object

Comment: What does "//this is not working" mean exactly anyway?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, the problem is I can't use any json object name. If I use the applications show the below error   Property 'fname' does not exist on type 'Book'"

Comment: "error ` Property 'fname' does not exist on type 'Book'`" is a lot better than "doesn't work". Do you get that error in the IDE or when you run the application?

Comment: In IDE show the error message as `Property 'username' does not exist on type 'Book'`

Comment: In application show the `Property 'fname' does not exist on type 'Book` Both places showing the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

confirm if you have these 2 properties inside your book model

```
export class Book{
  fname: string;
 lname: string;
}
```

and try this

```
this.observableBooks.subscribe(books => { 
          this.books = books,
          this.books.forEach(element => {
               console.log(element.fname);
               console.log(element.lname);
           })
          error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
 });
```